# How to get multiple sliders to work with java script/html/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, volume

I'm currently working on a site that hosts podcasts. I have it so the podcasts plays, but I can only get very first podcast volume slider to work; the second podcast's sliders moves, but doesn't change the volume at all. Each player has a "player" id that is used to identify it. I've everything else and am stuck on this one little bug. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the javascript that creates the sliders and tries to links them to each player:

```
<script>
audiojs.events.ready(function() 
{
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
    $('.slider').each(function() 
    {
        var slider = $('.slider'),
        tooltip = $('.tooltip'),
        audioList = document.getElementsByTagName("audio").length;
        console.log(audioList)
        tooltip.hide();
        slider.slider(
        {
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: 50,

        change: function()
        {


            for (var i = 0; i <= as.length; i++) 
        {
                //console.log(i)
            var value = $(".slider").slider("value");

            document.getElementById("player").volume = (value / 100);
        };
    },

    start:function(event,ui) 
    {
        tooltip.fadeIn('fast');
    },

    slide: function(event, ui) 
    {
        var volume = $('.volume'),
        value = $(".slider").slider("value");
        document.getElementById("player").volume = (value / 100);
        tooltip.css('left',value / 2).text(ui.value);
        if(value <= 5) 
        {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 0');
        }
        else if (value <= 25) 
        {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -25px');
        }
        else if (value <= 75)
        {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -50px');
        }
        else 
        {
            volume.css('background-position', '0 -75px');
    };
},
stop:function(event,ui) 
{
    tooltip.fadeOut('fast');
},});});}); </script>
```